# opening a batch file to get maximised cmd prompt from python

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file

*I am calling a batch file from python script

during execution, a command prompt opens.

My question is how to get a maximized command prompt window when a batch file is called from the python script ?*

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely positive, but I don't think that's possible from Python. A way to work around that is to create a shortcut for the batch file, right click the shortcut and set it up to run maximized in the shortcut's properties, then launch the shortcut from Python referring to it as a link (lnk) such as example below as used in Python 2.5:

```
import os;
os.startfile('C:\\batchfile\\test.bat.lnk')
```